# Flex Compiler Api: Adding images in Java

Tags: java, image, apache-flex, actionscript

I have a very specific question.
I want to compile an ActionScript project within Java in-memory with the help of the Flex Compiler API ( http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/compilerAPI_flex3.pdf ).

My last problem is to add images (jpg, png) that are embedded in the project to the compiler. I don´t see a possibility to do this in-memory and my attempt to add them from disk was also unsuccessful.

Hope someone has a good hint for me.

Greets, Konsumierer

Answer (score 0):

Invoking the flex compiler from java shouldn't be any different from invoking it from the eclipse plugin. I suppose you have the project located somewhere on the filesystem, so I suppose if the images are in the correct relative path, they should be embedded. How do you embed them, actually?

Another option is, in case when you use them in web-environment (and not AIR), to just write a relative server path to the image. For instance - the `.swf` is in `/`, you can poing the image to `/images/myimage.jpg`, and it will work.